# Android : Create a rounded image doesn't work for big photo

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I use the following code to create rounded ImageView :

**Class RoundedImageView :**

```
public class RoundedImageView {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

And i use it :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)viewHolder.imageUser.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        Bitmap bpRounded = RoundedImageView.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 2000);
                        viewHolder.imageUser.setImageBitmap(bpRounded);
```

For some photo, the result is not good :

[image]

Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: It is dependent on the pixel value you are passing to your function. The reason that image looks like that is that your pixel value is too high, so you end up with something like you have (too small and it will look like a normal/unrounded rectangle).

Comment: I tried to put 20000 instead of 2000 but i get the same result..

Comment: I try to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in ImageView.  The result is little different. How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: Try a smaller number, not a bigger one.